# Magento add products programmatically and redirect to checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a external site where you can add products directly from.

So I tried to create a php file which can receive some HTTP POST - but its not working.

First I tried some very basic

```
<?php
namespace Addtocart;

use Mage;

require __DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php';

/*
if (! isset($_POST, $_POST['data'])) {
    exit;
}
*/

$data = array(
    //array('id' => 2532, 'qty' => 1, 'attribute' => 92, 'value' => 11), // 002
    //array('id' => 1854, 'qty' => 1),
    array('id' => '5711914018542', 'qty' => 1)
);

Mage::app();

$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

/** @var \Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart */
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$errors = array();
foreach($data as $product) {
    try {
        $productid = (int)$product_model->getIdBySku($product['id']);

        $params = array(
            'product' => $productid,
            'qty' => $product['qty']
        );

        if (array_key_exists('attribute', $product)) {
            $params['super_attribute'] = array($product['attribute'] => $product['value']);
        }

        $p = $product_model->load($productid);
        $cart->addProduct($p, $params);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $errors[$product['id']] = $e->getMessage();
        continue;
    }
}

$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->setQuote($cart->getQuote());
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

if ($errors) {
    var_dump($errors);
    exit;
}

header('Location: /checkout/cart/');
```

But the cart is still empty.

Then I tried looking into the cart `var_dump($cart)` and found out that all products is actually added, so my guess is the session is changed between `Mage::app()` and `Mage::run()` is there any thing I can do to persist the session?

- Magento: 1.7.0.2

Comment: On the cart page that you redirect too afterwards you could try var dumping the quote id attached to the session and do the same for your post script (above) and compare the two to ensure that the quote id is the same. My guess is you are being issued on a new session id on the redirect to checkout/cart. Although magento has a cart object, the quote object is where the products ultimately reside.

Comment: `$cart->getQuote()->getId()` - is the same before and after the `header('location...')`

Comment: `session_id()` is also the same before and after

Comment: I added `$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');`to the top of the script and just before the redirect I added `$session->addSuccess('success');` and the success message show fine on the cart page - But still no items in the basket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code here can be used, it will add multiple products

```
<?php
namespace Addtocart;

require __DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php';
use Mage;

if (! isset($_GET, $_GET['p'])) {
    var_dump($_GET);
    exit;
}

Mage::app();

/** @var \Mage_Core_Model_Session */
$coresession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

/** @var \Mage_Checkout_Model_Session $session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session->start();
$session->clear();

/** @var \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product_model */
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

/** @var \Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart */
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->truncate();

$errors = array();
foreach($_GET['p'] as $product) {
    $product = json_decode($product, true);
    try {
        $productid = (int)$product_model->getIdBySku(urldecode($product['id']));

        $params = array(
            'product' => $productid,
            'qty' => $product['qty']
        );

        if (array_key_exists('attribute', $product)) {
            $params['super_attribute'] = array($product['attribute'] => $product['value']);
        }

        $cart->addProduct($productid, $params);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $errors[$product['id']] = $e->getMessage() . ' (Product: ' . print_r($product, true) . ')';
        continue;
    }
}

$cart->save();
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

if ($errors) {
    var_dump($errors);
    exit;
}

if ($cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
    var_dump($cart->getQuote()->getHasError());
    exit;
}


header('Location: /checkout/cart/');
```

And to use it send a GET request to the file with the following

```
p[]={"id":"<config-sku>","attribute":<attr>,"value":<value>,"qty":<qty>}&p[]={"id":"<simple-sku>","qty":<qty>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Magento's built in URL system for doing this as a get request from external site.

For simple products: `http://www.magentosite.com/checkout/cart/add?product=1001&qty=1`

You can also do custom options: `http://www.magentosite.com/checkout/cart/add?product=1001&qty=1&options[12]=57&options[15]=32`

Comment: The problem with that is you can only add 1 product, and that was not useable :)